# Cannot find my AAD app in the portal anymore

Tags: azure-active-directory

I've created an AAD application by using the below CMD let:

```
New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "My Name" -PublicClient $False -IdentifierUris "https://mytestapp.com"
```

The command completes with no errors and if I then query list of applications by executing

```
Get-AzureADApplication
```

I can see my application but if I go to https://portal.azure.com I am not seeing my app there. I remember for sure I did this multiple times in past and had no problem with it, has anything changed in the portal recently? I also noticed that all my apps in all my directories are not visible if I use a portal - it just shows that I don't have any apps but I can successfully use them to acquire tokens and can see them through PowerShell.

Comment: Are we talking about the dashboard or the all resources view?

Comment: Are you surely checking Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations? Also, maybe it was created in another tenant? If you are a member of multiple directories, try checking the others from the dropdown on the top-right.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you are signed into the right tenant. Use the tenant picker in the top right corner of the Azure Portal:

[image]

The fact that all your apps are missing makes me feel like you might simply be looking in the wrong place :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should ensure you select right Tenant on Portal.

Also, when you select, you should choose `All Apps` not `My Apps`, you should see the app.

[image]

Comment: Hi, do you find your app now? I am sure the answer should work for you.